# Logstash is unable to parse a valid JSON file

Tags: logstash, logstash-json

I have the following JSON file:

```
  { "UserId":"433157", "Username":"Thu Huynh", "Email":"THuynh+1@sphera.com", "Timezone":"Mountain Standard Time", "CompanyId":"343", "Operation":"POST", "Channel":"UI", "Path":"/api/v1.0/admin/accounts/users", "Context":"Accounts GetUsersForOAAccount", "Params": { "companyId":"343", "userId":"433157", "moduleId":"1" }, "Object":"", "EventType":"Field Value Change", "DateRequested":"09/06/2023 03:20:18", "DateCompleted":"09/06/2023 03:20:18" ,"ModifiedDate":"", "ResponseCode":"200", "ResponseMessage": { "userId":433157, "companyId":343, "userGuid":"B05DE331A3F540AB8748", "username":"Thu Huynh", "companyName":"EA-QA-Company", "hostName":"GoldenComplianceAssurance.spheracloud.internal.spherasolutions.com", "currentHierarchyId":0, "eaHierarchyId":0, "timeZone":"Mountain Standard Time", "timeZoneIANA":null, "timeZoneDisplayName":null, "currentLocationId":540132, "currentNodeId":543116, "currentModelId":13022, "userTypeId":4, "emailAddress":"THuynh+1@sphera.com", "openId":null, "accountId":0, "isSuperAdmin":0, "isLastActiveTenantDisabled":false }, "PreviousValue":"", "NewValue":""}
```

I have the following Logstash pipeline:

```
input {
# Read JSON files from the /logs/csv/ directory
  file {
    path => "/logs/json/*"
    start_position => "beginning"
    # remove this for not always starting from the beginning of the file
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    codec => "json"
    type => "json"
    mode => "tail"
  }
}

filter {
    # Parse JSON data
    json {
      source => "ResponseMessage"
    }
}

filter {
    # Lowercase company name for set the index name properly
   mutate {
    lowercase => ["companyName"]
   }
}

output {
  if [companyName] {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => [ "https://elasticsearch:9200" ]
      index => "log_data_%{[companyName]}"
      ssl => true
      cacert => "/usr/share/logstash/config/ca.crt"
      user => "elastic"
      password => "changeme"
    }
  }
  # Send data to stdout
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

When I run this pipeline (in Docker container) I get this error:

```
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       | [2023-09-12T00:31:44,384][WARN ][logstash.filters.json    ][main][fc661796945a71d1b7933530d67b2251967ffbbf026ff7feeab6a408fdd08a51] Error parsing json {:source=>"ResponseMessage", :raw=>{"currentModelId"=>13022, "isSuperAdmin"=>0, "timeZoneIANA"=>nil, "userId"=>433157, "hostName"=>"GoldenComplianceAssurance.spheracloud.internal.spherasolutions.com", "eaHierarchyId"=>0, "currentNodeId"=>543116, "currentHierarchyId"=>0, "username"=>"Thu Huynh", "currentLocationId"=>540132, "openId"=>nil, "accountId"=>0, "userTypeId"=>4, "userGuid"=>"B05DE331A3F540AB8748", "isLastActiveTenantDisabled"=>false, "emailAddress"=>"THuynh+1@sphera.com", "companyId"=>343, "companyName"=>"EA-QA-Company", "timeZone"=>"Mountain Standard Time", "timeZoneDisplayName"=>nil}, :exception=>#<Java::JavaLang::ClassCastException: class org.jruby.RubyHash cannot be cast to class org.jruby.RubyIO (org.jruby.RubyHash and org.jruby.RubyIO are in unnamed module of loader 'app')>}
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       | [2023-09-12T00:31:44,386][WARN ][logstash.filters.json    ][main][fc661796945a71d1b7933530d67b2251967ffbbf026ff7feeab6a408fdd08a51] Error parsing json {:source=>"ResponseMessage", :raw=>{"currentModelId"=>13022, "isSuperAdmin"=>0, "timeZoneIANA"=>nil, "userId"=>433157, "hostName"=>"GoldenComplianceAssurance.spheracloud.internal.spherasolutions.com", "eaHierarchyId"=>0, "currentNodeId"=>543116, "currentHierarchyId"=>0, "username"=>"Thu Huynh", "currentLocationId"=>540132, "openId"=>nil, "accountId"=>0, "userTypeId"=>4, "userGuid"=>"B05DE331A3F540AB8748", "isLastActiveTenantDisabled"=>false, "emailAddress"=>"THuynh+1@sphera.com", "companyId"=>343, "companyName"=>"EA-QA-Company", "timeZone"=>"Mountain Standard Time", "timeZoneDisplayName"=>nil}, :exception=>#<Java::JavaLang::ClassCastException: class org.jruby.RubyHash cannot be cast to class org.jruby.RubyIO (org.jruby.RubyHash and org.jruby.RubyIO are in unnamed module of loader 'app')>}
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       | {
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |           "CompanyId" => "343",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                "tags" => [
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |         [0] "_jsonparsefailure"
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |     ],
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                "Path" => "/api/v1.0/admin/accounts/users",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |          "@timestamp" => 2023-09-12T00:31:38.314148718Z,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |     "ResponseMessage" => {
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                     "currentModelId" => 13022,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                       "isSuperAdmin" => 0,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                       "timeZoneIANA" => nil,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                             "userId" => 433157,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                           "hostName" => "GoldenComplianceAssurance.spheracloud.internal.spherasolutions.com",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                      "eaHierarchyId" => 0,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                      "currentNodeId" => 543116,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                 "currentHierarchyId" => 0,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                           "username" => "Thu Huynh",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                  "currentLocationId" => 540132,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                             "openId" => nil,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                          "accountId" => 0,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                         "userTypeId" => 4,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                           "userGuid" => "B05DE331A3F540AB8748",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |         "isLastActiveTenantDisabled" => false,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                       "emailAddress" => "THuynh+1@sphera.com",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                          "companyId" => 343,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                        "companyName" => "EA-QA-Company",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                           "timeZone" => "Mountain Standard Time",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                "timeZoneDisplayName" => nil
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |     },
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |            "NewValue" => "",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |       "PreviousValue" => "",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |        "ModifiedDate" => "",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |       "DateCompleted" => "09/06/2023 03:20:18",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |             "Context" => "Accounts GetUsersForOAAccount",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |            "@version" => "1",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |              "Params" => {
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |            "userId" => "433157",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |         "companyId" => "343",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |          "moduleId" => "1"
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |     },
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |            "Username" => "Thu Huynh",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |       "DateRequested" => "09/06/2023 03:20:18",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |           "EventType" => "Field Value Change",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |             "Channel" => "UI",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |        "ResponseCode" => "200",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                "type" => "json",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |               "event" => {
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |         "original" => "{ \"UserId\":\"433157\", \"Username\":\"Thu Huynh\", \"Email\":\"THuynh+1@sphera.com\", \"Timezone\":\"Mountain Standard Time\", \"CompanyId\":\"343\", \"Operation\":\"POST\", \"Channel\":\"UI\", \"Path\":\"/api/v1.0/admin/accounts/users\", \"Context\":\"Accounts GetUsersForOAAccount\", \"Params\": { \"companyId\":\"343\", \"userId\":\"433157\", \"moduleId\":\"1\" }, \"Object\":\"\", \"EventType\":\"Field Value Change\", \"DateRequested\":\"09/06/2023 03:20:18\", \"DateCompleted\":\"09/06/2023 03:20:18\" ,\"ModifiedDate\":\"\", \"ResponseCode\":\"200\", \"ResponseMessage\": { \"userId\":433157, \"companyId\":343, \"userGuid\":\"B05DE331A3F540AB8748\", \"username\":\"Thu Huynh\", \"companyName\":\"EA-QA-Company\", \"hostName\":\"GoldenComplianceAssurance.spheracloud.internal.spherasolutions.com\", \"currentHierarchyId\":0, \"eaHierarchyId\":0, \"timeZone\":\"Mountain Standard Time\", \"timeZoneIANA\":null, \"timeZoneDisplayName\":null, \"currentLocationId\":540132, \"currentNodeId\":543116, \"currentModelId\":13022, \"userTypeId\":4, \"emailAddress\":\"THuynh+1@sphera.com\", \"openId\":null, \"accountId\":0, \"isSuperAdmin\":0, \"isLastActiveTenantDisabled\":false }, \"PreviousValue\":\"\", \"NewValue\":\"\"}"
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |     },
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |               "Email" => "THuynh+1@sphera.com",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                 "log" => {
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |         "file" => {
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |             "path" => "/logs/json/log.json"
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |         }
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |     },
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |            "Timezone" => "Mountain Standard Time",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |           "Operation" => "POST",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |              "Object" => "",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                "host" => {
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |         "name" => "6d8fb764b55b"
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |     },
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |              "UserId" => "433157"
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       | }
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       | {
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |           "CompanyId" => "343",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                "tags" => [
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |         [0] "_jsonparsefailure"
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |     ],
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                "Path" => "/api/v1.0/admin/accounts/users",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |          "@timestamp" => 2023-09-12T00:31:38.320068968Z,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |     "ResponseMessage" => {
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                     "currentModelId" => 13022,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                       "isSuperAdmin" => 0,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                       "timeZoneIANA" => nil,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                             "userId" => 433157,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                           "hostName" => "GoldenComplianceAssurance.spheracloud.internal.spherasolutions.com",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                      "eaHierarchyId" => 0,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                      "currentNodeId" => 543116,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                 "currentHierarchyId" => 0,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                           "username" => "Thu Huynh",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                  "currentLocationId" => 540132,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                             "openId" => nil,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                          "accountId" => 0,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                         "userTypeId" => 4,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                           "userGuid" => "B05DE331A3F540AB8748",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |         "isLastActiveTenantDisabled" => false,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                       "emailAddress" => "THuynh+1@sphera.com",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                          "companyId" => 343,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                        "companyName" => "EA-QA-Company",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                           "timeZone" => "Mountain Standard Time",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                "timeZoneDisplayName" => nil
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |     },
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |            "NewValue" => "",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |       "PreviousValue" => "",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |        "ModifiedDate" => "",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |       "DateCompleted" => "09/06/2023 03:20:18",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |             "Context" => "Accounts GetUsersForOAAccount",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |            "@version" => "1",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |              "Params" => {
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |            "userId" => "433157",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |         "companyId" => "343",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |          "moduleId" => "1"
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |     },
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |            "Username" => "Thu Huynh",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |       "DateRequested" => "09/06/2023 03:20:18",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |           "EventType" => "Field Value Change",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |             "Channel" => "UI",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |        "ResponseCode" => "200",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                "type" => "json",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |               "event" => {
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |         "original" => "{ \"UserId\":\"433157\", \"Username\":\"Thu Huynh\", \"Email\":\"THuynh+1@sphera.com\", \"Timezone\":\"Mountain Standard Time\", \"CompanyId\":\"343\", \"Operation\":\"POST\", \"Channel\":\"UI\", \"Path\":\"/api/v1.0/admin/accounts/users\", \"Context\":\"Accounts GetUsersForOAAccount\", \"Params\": { \"companyId\":\"343\", \"userId\":\"433157\", \"moduleId\":\"1\" }, \"Object\":\"\", \"EventType\":\"Field Value Change\", \"DateRequested\":\"09/06/2023 03:20:18\", \"DateCompleted\":\"09/06/2023 03:20:18\" ,\"ModifiedDate\":\"\", \"ResponseCode\":\"200\", \"ResponseMessage\": { \"userId\":433157, \"companyId\":343, \"userGuid\":\"B05DE331A3F540AB8748\", \"username\":\"Thu Huynh\", \"companyName\":\"EA-QA-Company\", \"hostName\":\"GoldenComplianceAssurance.spheracloud.internal.spherasolutions.com\", \"currentHierarchyId\":0, \"eaHierarchyId\":0, \"timeZone\":\"Mountain Standard Time\", \"timeZoneIANA\":null, \"timeZoneDisplayName\":null, \"currentLocationId\":540132, \"currentNodeId\":543116, \"currentModelId\":13022, \"userTypeId\":4, \"emailAddress\":\"THuynh+1@sphera.com\", \"openId\":null, \"accountId\":0, \"isSuperAdmin\":0, \"isLastActiveTenantDisabled\":false }, \"PreviousValue\":\"\", \"NewValue\":\"\"}"
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |     },
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |               "Email" => "THuynh+1@sphera.com",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                 "log" => {
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |         "file" => {
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |             "path" => "/logs/json/log.json"
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |         }
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |     },
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |            "Timezone" => "Mountain Standard Time",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |           "Operation" => "POST",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |              "Object" => "",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                "host" => {
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |         "name" => "6d8fb764b55b"
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |     },
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |              "UserId" => "433157"
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       | }
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       | {
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |           "CompanyId" => "343",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                "tags" => [
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |         [0] "_jsonparsefailure"
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |     ],
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                "Path" => "/api/v1.0/admin/accounts/users",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |          "@timestamp" => 2023-09-12T00:31:38.314148718Z,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |     "ResponseMessage" => {
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                     "currentModelId" => 13022,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                       "isSuperAdmin" => 0,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                       "timeZoneIANA" => nil,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                             "userId" => 433157,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                           "hostName" => "GoldenComplianceAssurance.spheracloud.internal.spherasolutions.com",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                      "eaHierarchyId" => 0,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                      "currentNodeId" => 543116,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                 "currentHierarchyId" => 0,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                           "username" => "Thu Huynh",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                  "currentLocationId" => 540132,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                             "openId" => nil,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                          "accountId" => 0,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                         "userTypeId" => 4,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                           "userGuid" => "B05DE331A3F540AB8748",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |         "isLastActiveTenantDisabled" => false,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                       "emailAddress" => "THuynh+1@sphera.com",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                          "companyId" => 343,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                        "companyName" => "EA-QA-Company",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                           "timeZone" => "Mountain Standard Time",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                "timeZoneDisplayName" => nil
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |     },
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |            "NewValue" => "",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |       "PreviousValue" => "",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |        "ModifiedDate" => "",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |       "DateCompleted" => "09/06/2023 03:20:18",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |             "Context" => "Accounts GetUsersForOAAccount",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |            "@version" => "1",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |              "Params" => {
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |            "userId" => "433157",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |         "companyId" => "343",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |          "moduleId" => "1"
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |     },
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |            "Username" => "Thu Huynh",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |       "DateRequested" => "09/06/2023 03:20:18",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |           "EventType" => "Field Value Change",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |             "Channel" => "UI",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |        "ResponseCode" => "200",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                "type" => "json",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |               "event" => {
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |         "original" => "{ \"UserId\":\"433157\", \"Username\":\"Thu Huynh\", \"Email\":\"THuynh+1@sphera.com\", \"Timezone\":\"Mountain Standard Time\", \"CompanyId\":\"343\", \"Operation\":\"POST\", \"Channel\":\"UI\", \"Path\":\"/api/v1.0/admin/accounts/users\", \"Context\":\"Accounts GetUsersForOAAccount\", \"Params\": { \"companyId\":\"343\", \"userId\":\"433157\", \"moduleId\":\"1\" }, \"Object\":\"\", \"EventType\":\"Field Value Change\", \"DateRequested\":\"09/06/2023 03:20:18\", \"DateCompleted\":\"09/06/2023 03:20:18\" ,\"ModifiedDate\":\"\", \"ResponseCode\":\"200\", \"ResponseMessage\": { \"userId\":433157, \"companyId\":343, \"userGuid\":\"B05DE331A3F540AB8748\", \"username\":\"Thu Huynh\", \"companyName\":\"EA-QA-Company\", \"hostName\":\"GoldenComplianceAssurance.spheracloud.internal.spherasolutions.com\", \"currentHierarchyId\":0, \"eaHierarchyId\":0, \"timeZone\":\"Mountain Standard Time\", \"timeZoneIANA\":null, \"timeZoneDisplayName\":null, \"currentLocationId\":540132, \"currentNodeId\":543116, \"currentModelId\":13022, \"userTypeId\":4, \"emailAddress\":\"THuynh+1@sphera.com\", \"openId\":null, \"accountId\":0, \"isSuperAdmin\":0, \"isLastActiveTenantDisabled\":false }, \"PreviousValue\":\"\", \"NewValue\":\"\"}"
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |     },
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |               "Email" => "THuynh+1@sphera.com",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                 "log" => {
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |         "file" => {
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |             "path" => "/logs/json/log.json"
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |         }
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |     },
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |            "Timezone" => "Mountain Standard Time",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |           "Operation" => "POST",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |              "Object" => "",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                "host" => {
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |         "name" => "6d8fb764b55b"
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |     },
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |              "UserId" => "433157"
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       | }
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       | {
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |           "CompanyId" => "343",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                "tags" => [
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |         [0] "_jsonparsefailure"
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |     ],
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                "Path" => "/api/v1.0/admin/accounts/users",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |          "@timestamp" => 2023-09-12T00:31:38.320068968Z,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |     "ResponseMessage" => {
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                     "currentModelId" => 13022,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                       "isSuperAdmin" => 0,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                       "timeZoneIANA" => nil,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                             "userId" => 433157,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                           "hostName" => "GoldenComplianceAssurance.spheracloud.internal.spherasolutions.com",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                      "eaHierarchyId" => 0,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                      "currentNodeId" => 543116,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                 "currentHierarchyId" => 0,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                           "username" => "Thu Huynh",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                  "currentLocationId" => 540132,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                             "openId" => nil,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                          "accountId" => 0,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                         "userTypeId" => 4,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                           "userGuid" => "B05DE331A3F540AB8748",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |         "isLastActiveTenantDisabled" => false,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                       "emailAddress" => "THuynh+1@sphera.com",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                          "companyId" => 343,
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                        "companyName" => "EA-QA-Company",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                           "timeZone" => "Mountain Standard Time",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                "timeZoneDisplayName" => nil
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |     },
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |            "NewValue" => "",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |       "PreviousValue" => "",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |        "ModifiedDate" => "",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |       "DateCompleted" => "09/06/2023 03:20:18",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |             "Context" => "Accounts GetUsersForOAAccount",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |            "@version" => "1",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |              "Params" => {
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |            "userId" => "433157",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |         "companyId" => "343",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |          "moduleId" => "1"
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |     },
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |            "Username" => "Thu Huynh",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |       "DateRequested" => "09/06/2023 03:20:18",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |           "EventType" => "Field Value Change",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |             "Channel" => "UI",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |        "ResponseCode" => "200",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                "type" => "json",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |               "event" => {
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |         "original" => "{ \"UserId\":\"433157\", \"Username\":\"Thu Huynh\", \"Email\":\"THuynh+1@sphera.com\", \"Timezone\":\"Mountain Standard Time\", \"CompanyId\":\"343\", \"Operation\":\"POST\", \"Channel\":\"UI\", \"Path\":\"/api/v1.0/admin/accounts/users\", \"Context\":\"Accounts GetUsersForOAAccount\", \"Params\": { \"companyId\":\"343\", \"userId\":\"433157\", \"moduleId\":\"1\" }, \"Object\":\"\", \"EventType\":\"Field Value Change\", \"DateRequested\":\"09/06/2023 03:20:18\", \"DateCompleted\":\"09/06/2023 03:20:18\" ,\"ModifiedDate\":\"\", \"ResponseCode\":\"200\", \"ResponseMessage\": { \"userId\":433157, \"companyId\":343, \"userGuid\":\"B05DE331A3F540AB8748\", \"username\":\"Thu Huynh\", \"companyName\":\"EA-QA-Company\", \"hostName\":\"GoldenComplianceAssurance.spheracloud.internal.spherasolutions.com\", \"currentHierarchyId\":0, \"eaHierarchyId\":0, \"timeZone\":\"Mountain Standard Time\", \"timeZoneIANA\":null, \"timeZoneDisplayName\":null, \"currentLocationId\":540132, \"currentNodeId\":543116, \"currentModelId\":13022, \"userTypeId\":4, \"emailAddress\":\"THuynh+1@sphera.com\", \"openId\":null, \"accountId\":0, \"isSuperAdmin\":0, \"isLastActiveTenantDisabled\":false }, \"PreviousValue\":\"\", \"NewValue\":\"\"}"
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |     },
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |               "Email" => "THuynh+1@sphera.com",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                 "log" => {
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |         "file" => {
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |             "path" => "/logs/json/log.json"
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |         }
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |     },
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |            "Timezone" => "Mountain Standard Time",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |           "Operation" => "POST",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |              "Object" => "",
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |                "host" => {
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |         "name" => "6d8fb764b55b"
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |     },
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       |              "UserId" => "433157"
eg_elastic_poc-main-logstash-1       | }
eg_elastic_poc-main-kibana-1         | [2023-09-12T00:31:47.120+00:00][INFO ][status] Kibana is now available (was degraded)
eg_elastic_poc-main-kibana-1         | [2023-09-12T00:31:47.129+00:00][INFO ][plugins.ml] Task ML:saved-objects-sync-task: No ML saved objects in need of synchronization
```

What can I change (either in the JSON file or in the pipeline) to parse this input without errors?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I had to change the "source" from "ResponseMessage" to "message"